# getViewData vs. getNormData and DataTransformers - different results depending on context

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form with several fields.

Then I bound `DataTransformer` to the one of them. Transformer works correctly if I get data `getViewData` and `getNormData`.

But if I issue these methods on whole form, data processed by transformers are completely ignored.

In `Form` data is being overwritten due to the:

```
$childrenIterator = new InheritDataAwareIterator($this->children);
$childrenIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($childrenIterator);
$this->config->getDataMapper()->mapFormsToData($childrenIterator, $viewData);
```

My mapper is `PropertyPathMapper`. Unfortunately, it bases on `getData` method of each child.

Is it possible to bypass `viewData` overwrite / achieve correctly transformed data without writing a global transformer?

Answer (score 0):

a workaround:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($form->all() as $k => $el) {
    $data[$k] = $el->getData(); // or getNormData or getViewData
}
```

Unfortunately I have no solution.

The current behaviour is not what I expected. It should at least be mentioned [in the symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).

---

As you see I have the same problem. I wrote a test case to be sure that I do not misunderstand how the transformers work. I found your question later.

my test case:
https://github.com/SimonHeimberg/SymfonyFormForm_DataTransformer_Demo

Comment: I've submitted an issue on their tracker: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18683