# How to get data through ModelTransformer

Tags: forms, symfony

Here is some code of my Type Class. For one of the property I use a ModelTransform to display what I want :

```
$builder->add('myProperty', 'text', array(
   'label' => 'MyLabel',
   'required' => true,
   'disabled' => true
));

$builder->get('myProperty')
  ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
       function($propertyFrom) {
                return (round($propertyFrom/ 100, 3)) + 1;
            },
            function($propertyTo) {
                return round((($propertyTo- 1) * 100), 3);
            }
        ));
```

it works good when I display my form in the twig.

I would like to get the entity from my form. I guessed, assuming I have my Form object, I would do like this :

```
$entity = $form->getViewData()
```

I wanted to have the entity with the value of the fields passed through the ModelTransform. Though I have the value of field with no transformation.

Finally I wonder what is the difference between $form->getData() and $form->getViewData().

How can I get the entity with the values transformed by my ModelTransformer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Symfony bug that does not apply transformer via the getViewData on the object. But it does it on the field.

[getViewData vs. getNormData and DataTransformers - different results depending on context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940228/getviewdata-vs-getnormdata-and-datatransformers-different-results-depending-o)

Comment: It isn't a bug but a kind of limitation https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18683#issuecomment-249676768

Answer (score 1):

> This is a kind of limitation because compound forms having an object or array as underlying data, don't keep their view data synchronized with their children's view data. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18683#issuecomment-249676768

You can get the difference thus:

```
// if myProperty value is equal to 23

$form->get('myProperty')->getData();     //output: 23
$form->get('myProperty')->getNormData(); //output: 1.23
$form->get('myProperty')->getViewData(); //output: "1.23"
```